# how to resemble add contact functionality of IOS native message App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, native

I need to resemble adding contact functionality of IOS native Messaga App. What all components can be used to achieve this. I expect some suggestions from You. A screen shot is given below which describes in which section i need help.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look at the following frameworks

[GCTagList](https://github.com/greenchiu/GCTagList)

[DWTagList](https://github.com/domness/DWTagList)

Comment: thank You a lot. Its very useful for me. I was trying to implement myself after searching internet i had not get any stuff.